# no operator << matches these operands visual c++

Tags: c++

I am having an error message that i cant figure out how ti get rid of. I am trying to have my program ask the user for the file name and then output a list of prime numbers from 1 - 100 to that file. I can get it to work if the file is an "ofstream outputfile;" that I specify but when I change it to an input file the error pops up. It is on line 28 right after inputFile. I have checked other questions on this and they all say to include the  header which I have done but it still doesn't fix the issue. I am new to programming so I appreciate your help and patience.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;

cout << "Enter a filename: ";
cin >> filename;

inputFile.open(filename);

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    isPrime(i);
    while (isPrime(i) == true)
    {
        inputFile << i << endl; //ERROR IS HERE!
        break;
    }

}
inputFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;

}

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++)
    {
        double x = n%i;
        if (x == 0.0)
            isPrime = false;
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: s/intput/output/

Comment: You need `std::ofstream` to write to a file, not `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Btw, this `isPrime(i);` does nothing at all and please change this: `while (isPrime(i) == true)` to an `if` statement and remove `break;`.

Comment: Thanks @DimChtz. I have made all of the changes you suggested and now the program runs great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ `operator <<` is user for output to output streams (like `std::ofstream`), and `operator >>` is used for input streams (like `std::ifstream`).

So, replacing `ifstream` to `ofstream` will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write something in the file

Instead of declaring an ifstream object declare a ofstream object that will fix your problem

Comment: "And make shure you remove that endl" Why? Writing new lines to a file is valid.

Comment: so if i want the user to enter the file name that it will be saved too I need to use ifstream and then also have an ofstream to write my function to the specified file?

Comment: @tim_weaver No, `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` (`std::fstream` in general) exist to read and write a file. When you want to read user input you use `std::cin`, `std::getline`, etc.

Comment: If you have to read as well as write in the file you have to declare an object of fstream